# Setup Postfix Mail Server in Ubuntu 10.xx for a VirtualHost

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp

I want to work with Postfix in Ubuntu 10.xx (.04 or .10) so that one of my virtualhost is the domain name or "mail name" as the configuration calls it for Postfix. How do I do this? ANd how do I configure the SMTP username and SMTP password for this?

Thanks in advance, and if this happens to be a duplicate, feel free to close it and point me to the related question.

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/Setting_up_an_email_server_in_CentOS

http://workaround.org/ispmail/etch

very useful links mayl help :)